# insert data with image into database

Tags: php, html

i want to insert both data and image into my sql database but if i fill the form and enter it the record is not insert and no error message is shown please help

```
   <!--fourth container starts here-->

                                 <div class="urine_test_lue">

                                    <!--fourth urinalysis-->

                                    <div class="urine_test_label">

                                        <label class="label">sg:</label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="urine_test_lue-main">

                                        <div class="urine_test_lue-sub">
                                            <div>
                                                <abel class="label">1.000</abel> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <input type="radio" name="urine" value="sg 1.000">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
    
                                        <div class="urine_sub">
                                            <div>
                                                <label class="label">1.005</label> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <input type="radio" name="urine" value="sg 1.005">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="urine_test_lue-sub">
                                            <div>
                                                <label class="label">1.010</label> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <input type="radio" name="urine"value="sg 1.010">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
    
                                        <div class="urine_sub">
                                            <div>
                                                <label class="label">1.015</label> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <input type="radio" name="urine" value="sg 1.015">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="urine_test_lue-sub">
                                            <div>
                                                <label class="label">1.020</label> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <input type="radio" name="urine" value="sg 1.020">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
    
                                        <div class="urine_sub">
                                            <div>
                                                <label class="label">1.025</label> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <input type="radio" name="urine" value="sg 1.025">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="urine_test_lue-sub">
                                            <div>
                                                <label class="label">1.030</label> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <input type="radio" name="urine" value="sg 1.030">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- image upload -->

                        <div class="system__container">

                            <label  class="form_label" for="name">select image files </label>

                            <input type="text" class="form_input" id="name" name="tittle" placeholder="enter image tittle" required>

                            <input type="file" name="image">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="personal__data--tittle">

                        <h3 class="u-margin-bottom-small u-margin-top-small">
                            completed by
                        </h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form_group">

                        <label for="name2" class="form_label">Name</label>

                        <input type="text" class="form_input" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="personnel_name" required>
              
                        <label for="designation" class="form_label">Designation</label>
                        
                        <input type="text" class="form_input" id="designation" placeholder="designation" name="designation" required>
                    </div>

                    <div>

                        <label for="sign" class="form_label">Signature</label>
                        
                        <input type="text" class="form_input" id="sign" placeholder="signature" name="signature" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="button_container">
                        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="enter record" class="submit_btn">
                    </div>
```

here is my php code

```
<?php

//database connection
$db = mysqli_select_db($con,'nesthet');

if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{   
    //personal data
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $reg_nurse = $_POST['reg_nurse'];
    $current_complain = $_POST['current_complain'];

    // vital
    $blood_pressure = $_POST['bp'];
    $temp = $_POST['temp'];
    $pr = $_POST['pr'];
    $rr = $_POST['rr'];
    $sat_02 = $_POST['02_sat'];

    // examination
    $illness = $_POST['illness'];

    $opt = $_POST['optional'];
    $optional = implode (',',$opt);

    $jaundice = $_POST['jaundice'];
    $edema = $_POST['edema'];

    // human system
    $respiratory = $_POST['respiratory_system'];
    $cardiovascular = $_POST['cardiovascular_system'];
    $nervous = $_POST['internal_nervous_system'];
    $gastro = $_POST['gastro_intestinal_system'];
    $differential = $_POST['differential_diagnosis'];
    $final = $_POST['final_diagnosis'];
    $treatment = $_POST['treatment'];
    $health_education = $_POST['health_education'];

    //routine lab test
    $rbs = $_POST['rbs'];
    $fbs = $_POST['fbs'];
    $hb = $_POST['hb'];
    $blood_group = $_POST['b_group'];
    $rdt = $_POST['rdt'];
    $wbc = $_POST['wbc'];

    //urinalysis
    $urine = $_POST['urine'];

    // image upload codes
    $tittle = $_POST['tittle'];
    $img = $_FILES['image']['name'];

    // complete by

    $personnel_name = $_POST['personnel_name'];
    $designation = $_POST['designation'];
    $signature = $_POST['signature'];

     //sql insert query

     $insert_query = ("INSERT into tbl_nursing_assessment (name , gender , date , reg_nurse , current_complain , bp , temp , pr , rr , 02_sat , illness , optional , jaundice , edema , respiratory_system , cardiovascular_system , internal_nervous_system , gastro_intestinal_system , differential_diagnosis , final_diagnosis , treatment , health_education , rbs , fbs , hb , b_group , rdt , wbc , urine , tittle , image , personnel_name , designation , signature)
     VALUES ('$name' , '$gender' , '$date' , '$reg_nurse' , '$current_complain' , '$blood_pressure ' , '$temp ' , '$pr' , '$rr' , '$sat_02' , '$illness' , '$optional' , '$jaundice' , '$edema' , '$respiratory' , '$cardiovascular' , '$nervous' , '$gastro' , '$differential' , '$final' , '$treatment' , '$health_education ' , '$rbs' , '$fbs' , '$hb' , '$blood_group' , '$rdt' , '$wbc' , '$urine' , '$tittle' , '$img' , '$personnel_name' , '$designation' , '$signature')");

     //run sql insert query

     if(mysqli_query($con,$insert_query))
     {
         echo "<script> alert ('Record inserted Successfully') </script>";
     }
     else
     {
        echo "<script> alert ('Record Failed to inserted please try again') </script>";
     }
}
//move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "uploaded_files/$img");

?>
```

Comment: Where are you saving the image into the DB or onto the server into a directory?

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input. It's not just about security. If any value contains, for example, a single quote, your query will fail.

Comment: Also run a proper error message https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp

Comment: i am saving image to a database and also move it to a folder for future refference

Comment: you said i'm widely open sql injection can you explain to how to prevent it

Answer (score 0):

you are doing php server site submission, So you need to add form tag in your html. then have to mention action and method in the form tag. you can follow the following links.

form submission ref:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

file upload ref:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Great referral he is trying to upload an image only using a SQL string no parameters is set for the image and no directory is set